# How to increase the height of the info overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have 3 Images that has a h4 - title and a bit of text:

```
<div class="container5">
    <h1 class="title2">Avantages</h1>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="mosaic-block bar">
            <a class="mosaic-overlay" style="background: #000;">
                <div class="details">
                    <h4 class="overlay-title">TEST1</h4>
                    <p class="overlay-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.<p>

                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/mosaic/desroches.jpg" alt="image08" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="mosaic-block bar">
            <a class="mosaic-overlay" style="background: #000;">
                <div class="details">
                    <h4 class="overlay-title">TEST2</h4>
                    <p class="overlay-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/mosaic/mightyicons.jpg" alt="image09" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="mosaic-block bar">
            <a class="mosaic-overlay" style="background: #000;">
                <div class="details">
                    <h4 class="overlay-title">TEST3</h4>
                    <p class="overlay-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/mosaic/florian.jpg" alt="image10" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I'm using mosaic overlay images:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(function() {     
    jQuery('.bar').mosaic({
        animation   :   'slide'     //fade or slide
        });         
    });
});
```

I want have a bigger overlay to contain all text in my details div! How can I achieve that?Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fNvbK/3/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `height` of the overlay `div` and adjust the `bottom` offset accordingly.

```
.bar .mosaic-overlay 
{
  bottom: -120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNvbK/5/).

Comment: It worked but I don't want the title to show! Thanks

Comment: @user3350731 I have updated my answer to hide the title.